# how to remove a whole number part in java?

Tags: java, format, decimal

I have a double which value is set to 0.00. I need the print statement to display it as "$.00". So the whole number part is not displayed

Tried using String.format() method as well as substring method but it did not bring me anywhere...any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is it only `0` that you want to special case? What about `$9.00`?

Comment: Yes, there is only one value (final double) that needs to be displayed. So I just need to get rid of the whole number part so only ".00" is displayed. The dollar sign in the front is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void outputFractional(double value) {
    double whole = Math.abs(value);
    double fraction = whole - ((long) whole);
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("$.00");
    System.out.println(format.format(fraction));
}
```

Comment: How so?  Works fine for me.

Comment: I get these results for 0, >=1, <= 1: $.00
$1.00
-$1.00

Comment: Updated to display fractional amount

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of performing two steps. First format the value to two decimal places. Then use `String.substring` starting from the decimal place. Like,

```
double x = 9.99;
String withZero = String.format("%.2f", x);
System.out.printf("$%s%n", withZero.substring(withZero.indexOf('.')));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
$.99
```

Answer (score 0):

The simples solution is to use `DecimalFormat` and set the max number of integer digits to 0.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$.00");
formatter.setMaximumIntegerDigits(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand the question:

Try that one

```
        double amount = 0;
        System.out.println("$" + amount);
```

Comment: What I meant is that I have a double value 0, when printed I need it to be displayed as ".00". Meaning the whole number part needs to be hidden